# Decorate node text of tikz with common Latex macros

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sometimes Latex macros like `\huge`, `\color{red}` rather than node optional args'' provided by `tikz` are needed for me to give a style to ``node text'' of picture by `tikz`. This is all right as shown in the following MWE.

However, when I construct my macro \test which `/.expanded` must be used to pass args, I find it can not compile if macros e.g. \huge is used(please see the following code).

Args in b/.code must be a value(not macro) in my code. So in this condition, how to achieve my goal to use common Latex macro decorating node text in tikz?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,xcolor}
\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{%
      a/.store in=\aaa,a/.default={},
      b/.code={%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{
          \AtTextUpperLeft{
            \tikz\draw(0,0) --node{#1}(5cm,0);}}},
      c/.code={%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{
          \AtTextCenter{
            \tikz\draw(0,0) --node{#1}(5cm,0);}}},
    }
    \newcommand\test[2][]{%
      \pgfkeys{a,#1,#2/.expanded={\aaa}}
    }
    %
    \test[a=aaa]{b}
    \test[a=777]{c}
    \test[a={\huge\color{red} ttt}]{c}% Wrong!! a={\noexpand\huge ttt} can pass the compile, but it's boring to write \noexpand each time. #2/.expanded={\noexpand\aaa} causes overwrite of the node text. So is there a better way to deal with this problem?

    first page\clearpage second page
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\test{a={\noexpand\huge ttt}}` but what is the goal of this?

Comment: Thank you @marnot. I modified my code to give more information and clearifid my goal.